# Dealing with background processes in bash

Tags: bash, background-process

I have two background processes 1 and 2

```
./1.sh &
 PID_1 = $!

./2.sh &
 PID_2 = $!
```

I'm trying to identify the process that finishes first and then kill that process which is still continuing. This is the script I'm working on.

```
while ps -p | grep " $PID_1"
do
     ## process 1 is still running
     ### check for process 2

     if ! ps -p | grep "$PID_2" 
     then
          ### process 2 is complete, so kill process 1
          kill $PID_1
     fi
done

kill $PID_2 ## process 2 is still running, so kill it
```

While this script works, I'm looking if there is any other better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use this simple approach for this task:

1. Use **`trap SIGCHLD`** to register a custom handler at the start of your script.
2. Every time a background (child) process exits, this custom handler will be invoked.
3. Inside the custom handler use **`jobs -l`** to see which child process is still running and `kill` it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wait. Something like ...

```
 (1.sh& wait $!; killall 2.sh)&
 (2.sh& wait $!; killall 1.sh)&
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
while true
   do

     res1=`ps -p | grep -c "$PID_1"`
     res2=`ps -p | grep -c "$PID_2"`
#grep command itslef will consume one pid hence if grep -c = 1 then no process else if greator than process is running 
    if [ $res1 -eq 1 ]
     then
      kill -9 $PID_2;
      exit 
     #exit while loop and script
   elif [ $res2 -eq 1 ]
      kill -9 $PID_1;
      exit
     #exit while loop and script
   fi
done
```

grep -c will give number of lines with that pid
since grep will have atlest one output in ps -ef as it also runs as a PID it have atleast 1 result

even if you ps -ef | grep someID
will have one pid for grep